# Show confirm popup while deleting file from 'Delete' button

Tags: debian, delete, deepin, deepin-desktop-environment

I have just installed "Deepin 20" and it is running fine. Now issue is that when I delete a file by pressing a Delete button then it deletes file immediately. If I delete it with `shift+delete` then it shows confirmation but it delete it permanently. I just want that it should show a confirmation popup then it should proceed and not delete permanently. I have tried to place alias rm='rm –I' in ~/.bashrc but it does not work. If there is a solution for this then kindly provide it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Nautilus/Gnome Files which comes bundled with the Deepin distribution.

In this program, when you select a file and press `Delete` on your keyboard it moves the file to the *Waste Basket*, immediately. You can easily undo this operation.

When you select a file and press `Shift`-`Delete` it will permanently remove the file, bypassing the Waste Basket. As a safeguard, it will ask you for confirmation before it does so.

This is the same behavior as most other file managers, even on Windows and MacOS.

Comment: But I want to change this behavior. It should show confirmation on normal delete